# jsp encoding does not display character correctly

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

Trying to display the following letter **š** (which is Lithuanian and which is under UTF-8 support according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_nls003.htm) on .jsp . In editing mode when trying to save text containing the letter Eclipse complains:

[image]

If it is saved as UTF-8 following the advice the complaints stop, but instead of **š** I get:

[image: clearly **š** not]

Current configuration:

Resource => explicitly set to other: UTF-8

Preferences => Web => ISO 10646/ UNICODE UTF-8

Loading files => User workspace encoding : YES

How the letter should look like(example): http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lietuvi%C5%A1kai

I am totally clueless.

Answer (score 7):

My fault, forgot to add:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

at the top of the .jsp file. Hope that helps anyone.

Comment: I develop web app JSPs with Eclipse IDE and this would automatically generated by the JSP template. But the `charset` variable do affects the output of characters with default encoding _ISO 8859-1_ (e.g. _Mandarin_).